# SQLITEASSETHELPER proper upgrade script

Tags: android, sqlite

I don't understand the documentation and I'm worried of accidentally dropping my table in my DB and corrupting the original file if I do this wrong.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

in reference to adding a column with values. The following code is provided via the creators git-hub sample

```
    -- add a FullNames column to Employees
ALTER TABLE "Employees" RENAME TO 'Employees_ME_TMP';

CREATE TABLE "Employees" 
(
    "EmployeeID" int NOT NULL,
    "LastName" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    "FirstName" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    "FullName" varchar(150),
    PRIMARY KEY ("EmployeeID")
);

INSERT INTO "Employees"  
(
    "EmployeeID", 
    "LastName", 
    "FirstName", 
    "FullName"
) 
SELECT 
    "EmployeeID", 
    "LastName", 
    "FirstName", 
    "FirstName" || ' ' || "LastName" 
FROM 
    "Employees_ME_TMP";

DROP TABLE "Employees_ME_TMP";
```

If I need to add two columns and then insert a bunch values into those to columns, would this be the right syntax?

```
    -- add a FullNames column and NickName to Employees
ALTER TABLE "Employees" RENAME TO 'Employees_ME_TMP';

CREATE TABLE "Employees" 
(
    "EmployeeID" int NOT NULL,
    "LastName" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    "FirstName" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    "FullName" varchar(150),
    "NickName" varchar(150),
    PRIMARY KEY ("EmployeeID")
);

    INSERT INTO Employees (FullName, NickName)
    VALUES ('Tyler Durden','Jack')
    WHERE rowid = 18;

    INSERT INTO Employees (FullName, NickName)
    VALUES ('Donnie Darko','Jake')
    WHERE rowid = 19;

DROP TABLE "Employees_ME_TMP";
```

Comment: INSERT adds rows, not columns.

Comment: @CL http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm would suggest otherwise. But okay, so how would I fix this to "insert or add" VALUES into the appropriate row in respect to the rowid and the correct column name?

Comment: "The SQLite INSERT INTO Statement is used to add new rows of data into a table in the database."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) says:

> The INSERT statement … creates one or more new rows in an existing table.

Your new table is empty, so you actually want to create rows, but the data in those rows must come from the old table. So you must use the SELECT form of the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName)
SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName FROM Employees_ME_TMP;
```

The other columns not mentioned in the INSERT will be filled with their default values (NULL in this case).
Then you have to put the new values into those columns.
Changing rows is done with the [UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html):

```
UPDATE Employees
SET FullName = 'Tyler Durden',
    NickName = 'Jack'
WHERE EmployeeID = 18;

UPDATE Employees
SET FullName = 'Donnie Darko',
    NickName = 'Jake'
WHERE EmployeeID = 19;
```

Comment: Do you know why it is necessary then, to ( ALTER TABLE "Employees" RENAME TO 'Employees_ME_TMP'; ) ? *Couldn't I just* **( ALTER TABLE Employees ADD COLUMN "FullName" TEXT )**  , *instead of having to fill out the entire table again* , when I only need to update two columns?

Comment: SQLite's ALTER TABLE is rather limited, so the SQLiteAssetHelper shows the mechanism that works in all cases. When ALTER TABLE works, you can use it.